# python3 Get a random IP based on CIDR notation i am

Tags: python-3.x

In python there are few modules supporting lot of operations on IP i want to get a random IP ( v4 or **v6 )** based on CIDR passed or choosen is there a way to do that, I have tried "netaddr" and **ipaddress** modules ?

```
>>> ip = IPNetwork('192.0.2.0/24')
>>> ip
IPNetwork('192.0.2.0/24')
>>> ip.ip
IPAddress('192.0.2.0')
>>> ip.network, ip.broadcast
```

I can get by below method a list but issue is again the returned list could be large and can eat complete memory

/64 prefixes  of the large amount of addresses

```
>>list(IPv6Network("2001:db8:0:1::/125").hosts())
    (IPAddress('192.0.2.0'), IPAddress('192.0.2.255'))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import ipaddress
ips = ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.0.0/24')
for ip in ips: print(ip)
```

more information in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/ipaddress.html)

Comment: if we do for /2 it will take huge time also for IPv6